# I can't insert related table field

Tags: typeorm

These are my tables:

```
@Entity('personas')
export class Personas {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    @IsNumber()
    id: number;

    @Column({type:"varchar",length:100})
    @IsNotEmpty()
    nombre: string;
    
    @OneToMany(type => Contactos, contactos => contactos.idpersona, {cascade: true})
    contactos : Contactos[] 
    
}

@Entity('contactos')
export class Contactos {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  @IsNumber()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  idpersona: number;
  @ManyToOne(type => Personas, {
  })
  @JoinColumn({name: "idpersona"})
  persona: string;

  @Column({type:"varchar",length:100})
  nombre: string;

  @Column({type:"varchar",length:11})
  telefono: string;
   
}
```

This is the body of the query to add the records:

```
{
    "nombre":"TestPersona",
    "contactos":[{      
                "nombre":"TestContacto",
                "telefono": "123456789"}
                ]
}
```

This is the error: [ExceptionsHandler] Field 'idpersona' doesn't have a default value.

It is assumed that the field idPersona in Contacts, should be inserted automatically. What am I doing wrong?. From already thank you very much.

Comment: What function are you calling to store the data?

Comment: This is my save function:                                                                                    `async agregar(tablaNueva: Personas): Promise<Number> {
    const tabla = new Personas()
    const tablaGuardada = Object.assign(tabla, tablaNueva)
    await this.repository.save(tablaGuardada)
    return tablaGuardada.id 
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I leave the way I fix it, in case it helps someone in the future.

In personas changed:

```
@OneToMany(() => Contacto, (contacto) => contacto.idpersona, {
cascade: ['insert']
})
public contactos: Contacto[]`
```

with:

```
@OneToMany(type => Contactos, contactos => contactos.personas,{
cascade : true,
})
public contactos: Contactos[];`
```

In contactos changed:

```
@Column()
@IsNotEmpty()
idpersona: number;
@ManyToOne(type => Personas, {
})
@JoinColumn({name: "idpersona"})
persona: string;`
```

with:

```
@ManyToOne(() => Personas, personas => personas.id, {nullable: false})
@JoinColumn({name: "idpersona"})
personas: Personas;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `cascade: ['insert']` and possibly add the `inverseSide` (second param) to `@OneToMany`:

```
@Entity({ name: 'persona' })
export class Persona {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id: number

  @Column()
  public nombre: string

  @OneToMany(() => Contacto, (contacto) => contacto.idpersona, {
    cascade: ['insert']
  })
  public contactos: Contacto[]
}


@Entity({ name: 'contacto' })
export class Contacto {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({
    name: 'id',
  })
  public id: number

  @ManyToOne(() => Persona, (persona) => persona.contactos, {
    nullable: false,
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'idpersona' })
  @Column()
  public idpersona: string

  @Column()
  public telefono: string
}
```

Then you can do:

```
const persona = {
    nombre: 'nombre',
    contactos: [{
      telefono: '123456789',
    }]
  }

  const personaGuardada = await entityManager.getRepository('persona').save([persona])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Make the suggested changes, but it still gives the same error: `Error: Field 'idpersona' doesn't have a default value`

Comment: query:INSERT INTO `personas`(`id`, `nombre`) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?) -- PARAMETERS: ["nombre"]
query: SELECT `Personas`.`id` AS `Personas_id` FROM `personas` `Personas` WHERE `Personas`.`id` = ? -- PARAMETERS: [48]
query: INSERT INTO `contactos`(`id`, `idpersona`, `nombre`, `telefono`, `email`, `observaciones`) VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, ?, DEFAULT, DEFAULT) -- PARAMETERS: ["123456789"]
query failed: INSERT INTO `contactos`(`id`, `idpersona`,`telefono`) VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT) -- PARAMETERS: ["123456789"]
error: Error: Field 'idpersona' doesn't have a default value

Comment: What database are you using? I'm using postgres and the sql looks like `INSERT INTO "persona"("nombre") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id" -- PARAMETERS: ["nombre"]; INSERT INTO "contacto"("idpersona", "nombre") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id" -- PARAMETERS: [55,"123456789"]`

That "RETURNING" part is how postgres gives the generated id back to typeorm.

Comment: I am using Mysql.

Comment: In this issue https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3853 it's similar, though not throwing an error.  Someone suggested to add a `.create()` call before the `.save()` but they are also using postgres.